How to fine-tune Cura profile for Klipper?
I finally finished upgrading my printer to Klipper. After LOTS of hassle, at last I got the resonances tuned. The printer software is as good as it can be, the printer capabilities maximized there.
Now what is left is perfecting the Cura profile for optimal performance, to make proper use of the capabilities Klipper provided. And I'm overwhelmed and don't know where to start. I have a working, nice, "safe" profile left over from Marlin, with some tweaks (like startup g-code adjusted for Klipper), and it provides good quality, but all the speed advantage is sunken into nice safe speeds.
I have a general idea of what parameter in the profile affects what trait of the printout, but it seems like getting them all optimal will take unholy amount of trial and error, a crazy amount of test prints. So what's a good procedure to optimize the printer profile?
How do I go about fine-tuning the profile to utilize Klipper's speed without ruining quality?
